# Dependency out of sync (later version than required)

Tags: apt, dependencies

I am trying to run apt-get dist-upgrade( also when running apt-get install zip) but I get an error message that says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.38.46) but 3.2.0.39.47 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

My question(s):

What is linux-headers-server.

How is it possible to have a later version of linux-headers-servers but it cant upgrade?

Will -f cause things to horribly break?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a server (or don't need the server kernel) you can remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-server linux-headers-server
```

To prevent that you are left without kernels:

- In a desktop:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-generic
  ```
- Server:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-server
  ```